# Android How to create default gallery to Circular Gallery?

Tags: android, geometry, android-gallery

I want to create the gallery view like below image. i have goggled it a lot and have tried with carousel also. but i am unable to create it . can any one advice me to create ta view like that ? i have tried with the gallery view styles also. but i am haven't found anything.

Waiting for better response. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: This is not so hard. I have a library that arranges views into circle: https://github.com/dmitry-zaitsev/CircleLayout. It may not well suited for your purposes, but you can use as an example.

Comment: i will have a look and get back to you .

Comment: hi is it possible to make our gallery view to circle layout? because i want to add imageswitcher concept in that.

Answer (score 5):

You can use Gama API for this look [here](http://developer.digitalaria.com/devguide/gama/en/gama/wheel_android.php)

Comment: Hi , Is is possible to make the circle layout as semicircle layout ? because i have tried with setAngle but doesnt worked in gama api.

Comment: it looks it will work for android API above 14 only. ? can we able to give support from 2.2 ?

Comment: beyond this You'll have to create your own Gallery using ImageView draw image at runtime in such that it should look like circular Gallery

Comment: so we cant give support to less than 4.0 ? If we cant give support than its very difficult to use know

Comment: yeah dilip i am searching the possibility ways to draw the circular gallery. but i am not able to do it that .. can you know any ways ?

Comment: yeah u can have look this for coding help http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146145/Android-3D-Carousel

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27844/discussion-between-rajesh-and-dilip)